# Plot an XYZ times-series graph of mean raster pixel values saved in series of lists

Tags: r, time-series, raster, timeserieschart

I have mean monthly NDVI values from 2000 to 2020. These are in a series of lists and I now hope to generate a plot where y-axis = years (2000 to 2020), x-axis = month (Jan to Dec) and the mean pixel values are plotted across months for each year. Extracts from the structure of my data are shown below.

```
> str(main_results)

List of 21
 $ 2000:List of 12
  ..$ Jan: num 53175340
  ..$ Feb: num 53175340
  ..$ Mar: num 54210607
  ..$ Apr: num 63805825
  ..$ May: num 63264070
  ..$ Jun: num 55204852
 $ 2001:List of 12
  ..$ Jan: num 52421208
  ..$ Feb: num 52056380
  ..$ Mar: num 50644054
  ..$ Apr: num 54343907
  ..$ May: num 63450964
  ..$ Jun: num 31621584
 $ 2002:List of 12
  ..$ Jan: num 5.7e+07
  ..$ Feb: num 52948521
  ..$ Mar: num 53387318
  ..$ Apr: num 52480231
  ..$ May: num 60184070
  ..$ Jun: num 60203653
 $ 2003:List of 12
  ..$ Jan: num 5.9e+07
  ..$ Feb: num 46296245
  ..$ Mar: num 57454065
  ..$ Apr: num 51364984
  ..$ May: num 60912416
  ..$ Jun: num 54743738
 $ 2004:List of 12
  ..$ Jan: num 45387264
  ..$ Feb: num 47411237
  ..$ Mar: num 43121839
  ..$ Apr: num 58219650
  ..$ May: num 52421337
  ..$ Jun: num 4.8e+07
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work without trying it on your data but try x <- `lapply(main_results, rbindlist, idcol="year"); rbindlist(x) `

Comment: or `x <- lapply(main_results, stack) ; rbindlist(x) `. If you provide some of the data using `dput()` then I can have a look to see if it works!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried it but I got errors. "main_results" was gotten from a series of loops involving converting HDF to TIF, loading the TIFF, importing shapefiles used to mask the raster.tiff files down to calculating the monthly mean raster values.

Comment: OK, if you provide a reprex I (or someone) can help. First thing you need to do is get the data into a single dataframe. Then it will be easy to plot.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is stuck and needs the same help. I was able to solve the problem with this code written by one of my supervisors. This converted the results from a list into a data frame

```
res_mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(main_results), ncol = 12, nrow = 21, byrow = TRUE))
colnames(res_mat) <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                       "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
rownames(res_mat) <- 2000:2020
```